# Init select2 inside bootstrap modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2, bootstrap-modal

When I open modal for first time select2, date picker widgets are initialized properly. Then I replace modal content with other HTML using $('#myModal').html(data) and at this stage the widgets are not initialized.

Running .datepicker() on it's DOM element solves the problem, but running .select2() on it's input element with and without options does not work.

Any help will be very thankful.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution and it little bit strange. 
HTML inside the modal was replaced by:

```
$('.modal-content').html(html);
```

It works visually and I can see new content inside a modal, but widgets are not initialized. Changing this call to:

```
$('#ajax-modal-lg').find('.modal-content').html(html);
```

solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

*Just init the datepicker or other stuff, on the load modal event :*

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#myInput').datepicker();
  })
```

**Here is the doc** : http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The problem, actually, that this event was not triggered on HTML replacement. Please see my own answer...